# Zsh doesn't know my username and tilde-expansion is broken

Tags: zsh

I'm having an issue with a fresh install of Zsh (installed using Homebrew). It doesn't seem to support tilde expansion of usernames and the %n variable for the prompt is not showing my username.

```
@dal-w-asic13 ~
��� echo $PROMPT
${NEWLINE}%{$fg[magenta]%}%n@%m %{$fg[cyan]%}%~%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)${NEWLINE}%(?:%{%}��� :%{%}��� )

@dal-w-asic13 ~
��� export PROMPT="%n $"
 $export PROMPT="(%n) $ "
() $ echo $USER
scotth
() $ dirname ~/bin
/home/scotth
() $ dirname ~scotth/bin
zsh: no such user or named directory: scotth
() $
```

Comment: I guess, `echo ~scotth` also shows the error? In this case, I would for a test create a bash or ksh subshell and see, whether i.e. `echo ~scotth` works there. Perhaps it's not a problem with your zsh, but in your system.

Comment: echo ~scotth works in both bash and tcsh. It's only failing in zsh. I feel like there is going to be some dependency that zsh is using for tilde-expansion and it's missing or failing and zsh just isn't catching the error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It really looks like a broken zsh installation. Perhaps it is related to the Mac port of zsh. However, on my Mac (still using the old zsh 5.7.1), tilde explansion works as advertised. I suggest that you crosspost your question at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget to include the version of your MacOS, the version of your zsh, and (for the safe side) the `brew` command used to install zsh. BTW, since zsh already comes with the Mac, what happens if you use this pre-shipped zsh?